# Is there anyway to specify project-specific coding style that will get loaded in IntelliJ from a pom.xml?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, coding-style, pom.xml

If I have a Maven project, and someone is going to load the project by opening the `pom.xml` file in IntelliJ, is there anything I can put in the file or elsewhere in the project that will load project-specific coding styles into the IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Not by importing from a pom only. What you can do is add some IntelliJ files to the source code management tool. Idea saves its project specific code styles into /.idea/codeStyleSettings.xml - it may just picks it up after you imported the project via maven/pom.xml. I think it does not hurt to add a few other files too. Here is my .gitignore for intellij 13.1.5:

```
target/
# intellij settings files:
.idea/artifacts/
.idea/dictionaries/
.idea/copyright/
.idea/inspectionProfiles
.idea/libraries/
.idea/scopes/
.idea/compiler.xml
.idea/uiDesigner.xml
.idea/vcs.xml
.idea/rebel_project.xml
.idea/dataSources.ids
.idea/workspace.xml
```

Everything else is under version control. (some developers dont like that - I know - just wanted to mention it)

Comment: :-( That's unfortunate. I was hoping there'd be an IDE-agnostic way to do it.

Comment: hmmm well somehow. The eclipse code formatter settings can be exported. For IntelliJ you can use the Eclipse Code Formatter plugin to use those settings. 
But I think you would need some maven plugin to download those settings from somewhere (or take them from the project) and apply them to the current workspace. I have not seen such a thing but that may be around somewhere. Maybe there are plugins that use checkstyle configurations for the IDEs to show what they dont like. For maven itself there are checkstyle plugins.